# How to write the correct constructor for merely function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming

I wrote a simple float(float) function object following *c++ template metaprogramming*:

```
class float_func
{
    struct base {
        virtual float operator()(float a) = 0;
    };

    template <typename F>
        class wrapper : public base {
            public:
                wrapper(F& f) : f_(f) { }
                virtual float operator()(float a) {
                    return f_(a);
                }
            private:
                F f_;
        };

    public:
    template <typename F> float_func(F& f) : funobj_(new wrapper<F>(f)) {}
    float operator()(float a) {
        return (*funobj_)(a);
    };
    private:
    base* funobj_;
};
```

I'd like to use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include "my_float_fun.h"

struct FunObject {
    float operator()(float a) const {
        return a + 1;
    }
};

float Func(float a) 
{
    return a - 1;
};

typedef float (*FuncPtr)(float a);

int main()
{
    FunObject obj;
    FuncPtr ptr = &Func;
    float_func a = obj;
    float_func b = ptr;
//  float_func c = &Func; not compile
    std::function<float(float)> d = &Func;
    std::cout << a(1)  << b(2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the line commented out does not compile. On the other side, std::function works well.

How should I modify my float_fun class to support merely the function pointer itself(&Func) rather than a function pointer object(ptr)?

Comment: `float_func b = ptr;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `template <typename F> float_func(F& f) : funobj_(new wrapper<F>(f)) {}` where `F` is `FuncPtr` not `float`.

Comment: Also, what problem are you trying to solve that you wrote all of this instead of just using `base`?

Comment: @kfsone: I take F as FuncPtr; I am just learning type erasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `const F&`, or simply `F` in your `float_func` and `wrapper` constructors, since `&Func` is rvalue and cannot be converted to reference.